# How can I find TLS settings for Traefik running in Kubernetes containers, to stop allowing weak cipher suites?

Tags: ssl, docker, kubernetes, containers, traefik

I have some servers that have been flagged as allowing insecure TLS/SSL cypher suites, etc for HTTPS.  I need to get it corrected.  However, the web servers on them are running from Docker/Kubernetes containers, and I can't seem to find where the TLS config is even defined.  The following is my process so far:

1. I ran "sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 443" to see what process is listening on that port.   According to Linux, there is no process listening on 443.  But I can view the websites in HTTPS, so that can't be correct.
2. I ran "kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{range.spec.ports}}{{if .nodePort}}{{.nodePort}}{{.}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'"
   This is one I got from another serverfault question.  The result included:
   30573map[name:websecure nodePort:30573 port:443 protocol:TCP targetPort:websecure]
   I have heard that websecure is the Traefik Entrypoint for HTTPS traffic.  So I have to assume that Traefik is what is actually handling this traffic.
3. I ran "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces" to see what pod Traefik is running in.  There were a ton of unrelated pods, and I got fifteen different results like:
   "kube-system          svclb-traefik-c89bf034-5c9nz                                  2/2     Running     12 (17d ago)   187d" (with different random segments at the end) and one further down the results of:
   "kube-system          traefik-869787b8bc-nfqmt                                      1/1     Running     6 (17d ago)    186d".  At this stage I am not sure which of these traefik pods is the one running websecure, or if they are all handling it in some way.  Additionally, I have read that TLS settings are found in the dynamic configuration of Traefik, and that the dynamic configuration is loaded from a "Provider", which can be a file, a website, or other source.  But I don't know where that is specified in the case of these servers.  I have tried looking for things like docker-compose.yml files or traefik.toml files with minimal luck and not finding any that define the TLS ciphers allowed or that seem to point to the configuration that does.

So my question is, How can I find TLS settings for Traefik running in Kubernetes containers, to stop allowing weak cipher suites?  Thanks in advance for your help, and apologies for any formatting problems with this question...it's my first on this site!

Comment: Please reformat your code examples / config snippets as code. Thx.

Comment: Can you tell me where to find the format/standards for formatting them as code?  This is my first code question here.  Also, none of this is "code" in the sense of being part of a script or program, so should all CLI input and output be considered code for formatting reasons?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, there's no real standard, but Code-highlighting improves readability a lot.

Helpful links are:

[How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)
 and [Comment formatting](https://serverfault.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)